# ASP.NET Data Cache - Does Overwriting Imply Removal And Re-Addition?

Tags: asp.net, caching

If I add an item to the cache named "foo", and then add another item named "foo" to the cache before the first expires, will this trigger the CacheItemRemoved event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it just overwrites the item. The item-removed callback is not invoked.